# How to avoid transitive type dependencies?

Tags: generics, rust, architecture, decoupling

I am trying to learn more about structuring software with type parameters and traits. I can make my program work, I am just trying to improve decoupling.

When I depend on a type that has a type parameter, say `A<T>`, where the type parameter has a constraint it means that I also must depend on the constraint. For example,

```
fn x<T: C>(arg: A<T>)
```

Without specifing `C` the compiler complains that the trait bound `A: C` is not
satisfied. To me this doesn't make sense. I don't need `C` methods. `A`
may change with respect to `C` and that shouldn't affect me.

How do I avoid having to depend on `C`?

Here is a the relevant part from a [larger playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e760045350191a30b11b2e57af2c3011) I used to explore possible solutions. Totally contrived, my real code has four type parameters with different constraints.

```rust
mod auth {
    pub trait Authz {
        fn allowed(&self) -> bool;
    }
}

mod limiter {
    use super::auth;

    pub struct Limiter<T: auth::Authz> {
        pub m: T,
        pub data: i32,
    }

    impl<T: auth::Authz> Limiter<T> {
        pub fn limit(&self) {
            if ! self.m.allowed() { panic!("not allowed"); }
        }
    }
}

// Works but is depedendent on Authz for every method. How do I avoid naming Authz within service?!
mod service {
    use super::limiter;

    pub struct Service;

    impl Service {
        pub fn invoke<T: super::auth::Authz>(a: limiter::Limiter<T>) {
            a.limit()
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e760045350191a30b11b2e57af2c3011)

#### What I've done to try to understand

- I've read `rustc --explain E0207` which was excellent.
- I tried using `PhantomData` but that just moved the problem elsewhere.
- I tried using a trait for Limiter so that Service can depend on that alone. That is fine except I lose access to the fields of the concrete struct unless I make getters and add them to the trait. But I have a feeling this is the answer.

Comment: "Without specifing C the compiler complains that the trait bound A: C is not satisfied. To me this doesn't make sense. I don't need C methods. A may change with respect to C and that shouldn't affect me.", I didn't understand.

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but I'd personally remove the type bound form the struct `Limiter` itself. The definition of that struct doesn't need a type bound. If some of its methods need one, you can add the type bound there (i.e. to the surrounding impl block). This already reduces the number of times you need to repeat the type bound. You will still need the type bound on `invoke()`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time expressing it succinctly, that's probably why I can't find an answer with searching here or google. The idea is that I think should be able to add and remove constraints on a type parameter without having to change all the code that references the concrete type. Basically, how do i insulate myself from changes in `A`'s type parameter constraints? - does that help at all?

Comment: @SvenMarnach It took me a bit to understand what you meant by "struct doesn't need a type bound."  But I got it and it did lead to more purposeful code. And the methods that require different bounds (or none) are now grouped together nicely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not alone in thinking that it should be possible to omit the implied trait bound here. There is [an accepted RFC about implied trait bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2089-implied-bounds.md) that will allow you to omit the trait bounds in your example once implemented.

Implied trait bounds are already implemented in [the experimental constraint solver "chalk"](https://github.com/rust-lang/chalk), which is intended to be eventually integrated in the Rust compiler. According to the [tracking issue for the mentioned RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491) we will have to wait for this to happen before we will see support for implied trait bounds in Rust.

Comment: That RFC is very interesting, thanks! The "Guide-Level Explanation" seems to cover exactly my case. I think "implied trait bound" is the phrase/concept I was missing.